# Django-PayPal connect Signals to actions

Tags: python, django, paypal

How should I connect Signals to Actions in order to handle different types of transactions in Django-Paypal?

**Docs Link:** https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal

In item # 5 of the `README.rst` for `Django-PayPal` it says to:

*5. Whenever an IPN is processed a signal will be sent with the result of the transaction. Connect the signals to actions to perform the needed operations when a successful payment is recieved.*

And then it lists the different type of transactions:

*There are **four** signals for basic transactions:*

```
payment_was_successful
payment_was_flagged
payment_was_refunded
payment_was_reversed
```

So my question is, how do I map the signals with the custom `Signals` in the `Django-PayPal` module, and where should these `Signals` live?  In the `models.py` or a separate file?

If you know the answer can you give me a working example of one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the signals into a file that is imported automatically by Django.

It is common to put them in `models.py` as that fits the bill, though I think it's cleaner to put them in a separate file or files, for example:

```
myapp/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  signals.py
```

Then in `myapp/__init__.py` you could have:

```
from myapp.signals import *
```

As long as `myapp` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` your signals will be imported and connected by Django.

In `signals.py` you define your receivers as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions)

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

@receiver(payment_was_successful)
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    # Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
    if ipn_obj.custom == "Upgrade all users!":
        Users.objects.update(paid=True)
```